# Almost (crosses fingers) New User, getting Error: "This app can't run on your pc"

Tags: error

I am trying to install Tor in English, and have downloaded different Windows versions from here: 
https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html

I am running Win 8.1 on a Lenovo laptop.  I keep getting the message "This app can't run on your pc" on a big bar across my screen each time I try to double click on it.

I have downloaded the files by right-clicking on the 'sig' and then choosing "save as", as well as just clicking on it.  I then remove the "asc" from the end and double click to install.  That's when I get the error message. I have also tried right clicking on the files themselves (I downloaded different versions when the earlier ones did not work) and choosing Run As Administrator, but then I get a little windowed message that says: "Windows cannot find (then it gives me the path and name of the file)".  I have also gone into the files properties and "unblocked" them.  Nothing.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The application is under 32-bit, 64-bit or 32/64-bit link, depending on OS. (sig) contains only signature of the application, for integrity checking purposes.

Comment: OMG.  Unbelievable.  I can't believe I did not notice how what I thought were just the names (descriptions) of the files, were the links themselves.  Wow.  Mine might have just won for most clueless question ever.  Thank you for your kind reply!